# localhost refused to connect.Even after paache restart i am unable to hit localhost

Tags: apache

After the following command

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

I am getting the following error

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: Hi @JOKER. So... what is the output of `$ systemctl status apache2.service` then?

Comment: Issue is solved.
Seems like some files went missing.
So i just uninstalled and re-installed it again